# Getting content-type from HttpActionContext

Tags: c#, json, authorization, httprequest, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am trying to do an authorization of an endpoint based on a value passed in the body request.  For example, a siteID is passed in the body of the request & I want to do authorization based on if the user has the appropriate permissions to that site.

I have this working if the body request is passed as json, but not if it's form urlencoded.  And I can't figure out how to find that out beforehand.  Here is a snippet of my code that works with json data, but fails if body request is urlencoded.

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.Request;

                try
                {
                    var content = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
                    _siteId = jsonResult["siteID"].ToString();
                    actionContext.Response = UserWorker.UserValidation(_siteId, request) as HttpResponseMessage;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    actionContext.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the content-type from the Request object. Try this:

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.Request;

        try
        {
            var content = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var contentType = request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
            string _siteId = string.Empty;
            if (contentType.MediaType == "application/json") //JSON case:
            {
                dynamic jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
                _siteId = jsonResult["siteID"].ToString();
            }
            else // form urlencode case:
            {
                _siteId = content.Split('=')[0] == "siteID" ? content.Split('=')[1] : string.Empty;

            }

            actionContext.Response = UserWorker.UserValidation(_siteId, request) as HttpResponseMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            actionContext.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly except for the content.Split part.  I changed that line to `_siteId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(content).Get("siteID");`  Thanks!